# Custom View layout not changed after size has changed

Tags: android

I have a custom view in android.

```
public class NumberTextView extends View {
}
```

And i `override` the method of `onMeasure`.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int newWidth;
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    float scale = getMeasuredHeight() / (float) mNumbers.get("t0").getHeight();
    float ratio = 140 / 224f;
    mNumberWidth = (int) Math.ceil(height * ratio);
    mDotWidth = (int) Math.ceil(scale * mNumbers.get("dot").getWidth());
    mDotheight = (int) Math.ceil(scale * mNumbers.get("dot").getHeight());

    if (mNumber.contains(".")) {
        newWidth = (mNumber.length() - 1) * mNumberWidth + mDotWidth;
    } else {
        newWidth = mNumber.length() * mNumberWidth;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, getMeasuredHeight());
    Log.d(TAG, "onMeasure width " + getMeasuredWidth() + ", height " + getMeasuredHeight());
}

@Override
public void layout(@Px int l, @Px int t, @Px int r, @Px int b) {
    super.layout(l, t, r, b);
    Log.d(TAG, "layout " + l + ", " + t + ", " + r + ", " + b);
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    mNumber = number;
    requestLayout();
}
```

But the position of the view is error. Look at the log of `onMeasure` and `layout`.

```
D/NumberTextView: onMeasure width 2151, height 1146
D/NumberTextView: onMeasure width 630, height 336
D/NumberTextView: layout -535, 90, 1616, 426
D/NumberTextView: onMeasure width 2151, height 1146
D/NumberTextView: onMeasure width 630, height 336
D/NumberTextView: layout -535, 90, 1616, 426
```

The custom view is used in `RelativeLayout`.

```
<com.test.view.NumberTextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
</com.test.view.NumberTextView>
```

Look at the log of `layout`. The height of the view is correct when the view height changed from `1146` to `336`. But the width is not change.

```
336 == 426 - 90
630 != 1616-(-535)
```

`1616-(-535)` is the old width `2151`.

Comment: I don't get it... According to your log, the `height` has also changed from `2151` to `630`?!

Comment: I try to put the into `FrameLayout`, it's worked. The problem is only happened in `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @Leo Look at the log of `layout`.

    336 = 426 - 90
    630 != 1616-(-535)

`1616-(-535)` is the old width `2151`

Comment: can you clarify more, I still don't get your question..

Comment: @Leo I write the different at the last of question.

Comment: ah got it. I think it's probably because `onLayout` is called before `onMeasure`, the height is still correct because you never change it in `onMeasure` (`setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, getMeasuredHeight());`). You might want to call `requestLayout` inside `onMeasure` to ask the parent to relayout, but mind that it could also reproduce infinite recursion (depends on how the parent layout of your custom view works).

Comment: I think my above comment was wrong. I just double checked, in your log, clearly that `layout` was called after `onMeasure`, so what's most likely going on here is the parent of your custom view measures your custom view, get its measured width, but then "somehow" decides to not use the value (which is 630, maybe because the parent thinks it's too small!?)